# How do we denote the set of all numbers $a_n$ in a sequence $\{a_n\}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, notation

I have a question about terms and notation related to sequences.

There is an end-of-chapter problem in Chapter 22 of Spivak's *Calculus* that says

> ...prove that the set of all numbers $a_n$ actually has a maximum
> member

How can we denote this set?

$$\{ a_n: a_n \in Image(a) \}$$

seems to me to be correct. Is there some standard way of denoting this set?

Here is some context based on this particular chapter in the book

First, there is the following definition

> An infinite sequence of real numbers is a function whose domain is
> $\mathbb{N}$.

He then says

> From the point of view of this definition, a sequence should be
> designated by a single letter like $a$, and particular values by
>
> $$a(1),a(2),a(3),...$$
>
> but the subscript notation
>
> $$a_1, a_2, a_3,...$$
>
> is almost always used instead, and a sequence is usually denoted by a
> symbol like $\{a_n\}$. Thus ${n}$, $\{(-1)^n\}$, and $\{1/n\}$
> denote the sequences $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ defined by
>
> $$\alpha_n=n$$
>
> $$\beta_n=(-1)^n$$
>
> $$\gamma_n=\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: $\{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$. By the way, you should use $(a_n)$, not $\{a_n\}$, to denote a sequence.

Comment: Given the definition, your suggestion looks correct. Though it could just be written as $Image(a)$.

Comment: @ShawSa: I would say that $Image(a)$ would not be immediately understood by most mathematicians (and neither would $\{a_n:a_n\in Image(a)\}$, although this version is clearly inferior to your suggested improvement).

Comment: @TonyK I believe it would if it was understood that $a$ were a function. From the context, I think it's appropriate to use the notation of the book the OP is working out of. In general, I agree with you though. The notation you suggested is probably best (hence the up-vote), unless one wanted to use theorems about images of functions.

Comment: I think the most clear, unambiguous way of denoting the set would be $\{a_n : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Note that for *ANY* set $B$ we can write $B$ as $\{x|x\in B\}$.  So we can simplify your $\{a_n| a_n \in Image(a)\}$ can be written simply as $Image(a)$.  If you are assuming $a:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ is a function so that $a:n\mapsto a_n$ then, you are correct.  That set of all $a_i$ *IS* simply the image of the function (I honestly never thought of it that way).  But we can define a set by it's domain as easily.  $\{a_n|n\in Dom(a)\} = \{a_n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ is probably the must common way.  And IMO the must intuitive and readable.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Nice to see that you agree with me...

Answer (score 2):

$$\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
does the trick. For sequences, you might also encounter the notation
$$\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$$

If you feel like using a shorter (yet less standard notation), you could write the elements of the sequence as $a(n)$ (instead of $a_n$). Here you could use $a(\mathbb{N})$ or $\text{Im}(a)$ to denote the desired set (I would avoid this if you are not representing the elements of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as $a(n)$).

In general: let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function. Let $A\subseteq X$ be a subset. One generally uses the notation
$$f(A)=\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}.$$
In case $A=X$, we write $\text{Im}(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

So, it would just be the range or image of the sequence function.

So if $f:\Bbb N\to X$ is such  that $a_n=f(n)$, then you want $\rm{im}(f)=f(\Bbb N)$.